# SQL Alchemy. tuple_ func in queries and None values

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm having the following strange behaviour in sqlalchemy.

```
Session.query(Player).filter(Player.name == 'Elijah Millsap').filter(Player.birth_date == None).first()
{name: Elijah Millsap, team: []}
Session.query(Player).filter(tuple_(Player.name, Player.birth_date).in_([('Elijah Millsap', None)])).all()
[]
Session.query(Player).filter(tuple_(Player.name, Player.birth_date).in_([('Elijah Millsap', None), ('Chris Bosh', '1984-03-24')])).all()
[{name: Chris Bosh, team: []}]
```

It seems like the row where the col birth_date is null fails when querying using tuple_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That doesn't work because the comparison to `NULL` in SQL is `IS NULL`. The comparison `= NULL` produces `NULL` instead of boolean true or false.

In SQLAlchemy, the comparison `== None` is translated to `IS NULL`, but when you use `in_` the `NULL` gets put directly in a list of values, causing the RDBMS to evaluate it as `= NULL`, not `IS NULL`.

Unfortunately, in this case, the solution is not ideal. You'll have to pull out the tuples with `None`s in them and do an `or_`. Example:

```
.filter(or_(tuple_(Player.name, Player.birth_date).in_([('Chris Bosh', '1984-03-24')]),
            and_(Player.name.in_(['Elijah Millsap']), Player.birth_date.is_(None))))
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
    tup =[('Elijah Millsap', None), ('Chris Bosh', '1984-03-24')]
    tup_join = ['|'.join(filter(None,t)) for t in tup]  

    Session.query(Player).filter(func.concat_ws('|',Player.name, Player.birth_date).in_(tup_join)).all()
```